# IBM Container - su :cannot create child process: Resource temporarily unavailable

Tags: docker, containers, ibm-cloud, su

I'm trying to "su" in the container deployed in IBM Containers/Bluemix.
But it fails like this.

```
root@ubuntu142:/tmp# cf ic exec -it mysshd bash
[root@instance-001652d1 /]# adduser ubuntu
[root@instance-001652d1 /]# su - ubuntu
su: cannot create child process: Resource temporarily unavailable
```

This works fine in my local docker environment.
I also tried to "su" in the startup script( user is already defined ), but it also failed with the same message( from the log ).
( Actually, I'm trying to deploy DB2-Express-C using "su db2inst1".. )
Is there any restriction that "su" is prohibited in IBM container?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 9):

I've seen this problem in Centos 7 container instances only (it works fine for Ubuntu).

Here is the solution to fix it:

```
$ cf ic exec -it ads-centos bash
[root@instance-00173f1f /]# adduser ubuntu
[root@instance-00173f1f /]# su - ubuntu
su: cannot create child process: Resource temporarily unavailable
[root@instance-00173f1f /]# cd etc 
[root@instance-00173f1f etc]# cd pam.d
[root@instance-00173f1f pam.d]# vi su
** change all session variables to 'optional' and save changes **
** see how file should be below **
[root@instance-00173f1f pam.d]# su - ubuntu
[ubuntu@instance-00173f1f ~]$ id 
uid=1000(ubuntu) gid=1000(ubuntu) groups=1000(ubuntu)
[ubuntu@instance-00173f1f ~]$
```

Here is how the `su` file should be

```
#%PAM-1.0
auth            sufficient      pam_rootok.so
# Uncomment the following line to implicitly trust users in the "wheel" group.
#auth           sufficient      pam_wheel.so trust use_uid
# Uncomment the following line to require a user to be in the "wheel" group.
#auth           required        pam_wheel.so use_uid
auth            substack        system-auth
auth            include         postlogin
account         sufficient      pam_succeed_if.so uid = 0 use_uid quiet
account         include         system-auth
password        include         system-auth
session         optional        system-auth
session         optional        postlogin
session         optional        pam_xauth.so
```

Comment: Hi, Alex-san. Thank you for the answer. It works ! ( I'm using CentOS7 docker container over a ubuntu host. So your suggestion was exactly the one I needed.) I was also annoyed by a SSH fail symptom, but it was also resolved by your answer. Thanks!

Comment: I'm glad it worked for you. Would you mind accepting the answer?

Comment: Thanks for the solution! Now if someone could explain what exactly am I changing here, what are the implications and why this problem happens in the first place? E.g. are the defaults in the container for pam authentication too strict? What is the canonical way of setting up/changing the requirements via tools (I guess for scripting sed can be used).